# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}} \in L^{1}(0,2\pi)$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I need to prove that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}} \in L^{1}(0,2\pi).$

By Dirichlet's test $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges uniformly on intervals $[\delta, 2\pi-\delta], \delta>0$. I don't know how to prove that $f \in L^1$ but I thing the following fact may be useful. $$\int\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}dx=-\frac{\cos(nx)}{n\sqrt{n}}$$ and $F(x)=\sum \frac{\cos(nx)}{n\sqrt{n}}$ converges uniformly and absolutely on $[0,2\pi]$ by Weierstrass M-test.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Sum by parts for $n < 1/x$  to estimate that $F$ is $O(1/\sqrt x)$ which is integrable for $x>0$ near zero and that should be enough by periodicity and odd

Comment: @Conrand: Integrability is $f(x)$ is a little subtle. If you have a some estimates done, I would like to see them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the sine series

$$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\sin n x}{\sqrt{n}}$$

The coefficients $c_n:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ form a decreasing sequence converging to $0$, and
$$
\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{c_n}{n}=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}<\infty$$
Therefore

1. $f\in L_1(\mathbb{T})$, and
2. $S_n(x)=\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{\sin kx}{\sqrt{k}}$ converges in $L_1(\mathbb{T})$ to $f(x)$.

Here, I am using the following result for special type of trigonometric series(See [F. Jones, Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean space](https://books.google.com/books?id=3U7tresTD1AC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), pp. 437 for example).

---

**Theorem:** Suppose $c_n\searrow0$.
$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq1} c_n\sin nx$ is in $L_1(\mathbb{T})$ iff  $\sum_n\frac{c_n}{n}<\infty$. In either case, $S_n(x)=\sum^n_{k=1} c_k\sin kx$ converges to $f$ in $L_1$.

---

**Ideas of the proof of Theorem**: In one direction, namely that $f\in L_1(\mathbb{T})$ implies the convergence of $\sum_n\frac{c_n}{n}$ follows from a more general result that can be found [here](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-trigonometric-series-that-is-not-a-fourier-series-lebesgue/). One may also construct a specific proof for the case of sine series of the type considered in the statement of the Theorem (See reference).

On the other direction, the reference above shows that convergence of $\sum_n\frac{c_n}{n}$ implies that $S_n(x)$ converges in $L_1(\mathbb{T})$. This is done by

1. Showing that $c_n\log n=o(1)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$
2. The sine kernel $K_n(x)=\sin x+\ldots \sin nx$ satisfies $\|K_n\|_{L_1(\mathbb{T})}=O(\log (n+1))$.
3. Using summation by parts, one shows that
   $$\|f-S_n\|_{L_1(\mathbb{T})}\leq \kappa\sum_{n>N}\frac{c_n}{n}+2\kappa c_{N+1}\log(N+1)$$
   for some constant $\kappa>0$.

**Edit:**
F. Jone's gives no references for this result, but I suppose this is well known to every Harmonic Analyst. Hopefully someone who reads this answer can provide more references. I ignore if [Zigmund's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=W9AxAjSiIaUC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) contain these sort of results.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: (+1)  Well done my friend

Answer (score 1):

Once you know that the Fourier transform of $$g(t) = |t|^{-1/2} sign(t)$$
is $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty sign(t) |t/\omega|^{-1/2}e^{-i t}d(t/\omega)
=c\ sign(\omega) |\omega|^{-1/2}$$

Then $$f(t)=C\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty g(t+2\pi m)$$
For $t\in [-\pi,\pi]$ it gives $$f(t)=C|t|^{-1/2}sign(t)+C\sum_{m\ge 1} ((t+2\pi m)^{-1/2}-(2\pi m-t)^{-1/2})$$ and the latter series converges to a continuous
(and analytic) function.

Comment: Dear @reuns, I am having a little difficulty digesting your answer. For starters, $g(t)=|t|^{-1/2}\operatorname{sign}(t)$ is not even in $L_2(\mathbb{R})$, so the Fourier transform in your second formula must be in the sense of distributions (perhaps?)

Comment: If you want. You can look at the Fourier transform of $g(t) e^{-\epsilon |t|}$ and let $\epsilon\to 0$, it converges without problems to a continuous function away from $0$ where it converges in $L^1_{loc}$.