# For $\alpha \in \left(0, \frac{1}{2}\right)$, $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^{\alpha}}$ is not the Fourier series of a RI-function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, fourier-series, pointwise-convergence

I am having a bit of trouble trying to show that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^{\alpha}}$ for $\alpha \in \left(0, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ is not the Fourier series of a RI-function.

I have shown that the series is pointwise convergent by Dirichlet's test for a fixed $x$, since the sequence of partial sums of $\sin(nx)$ is bounded, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
\left|\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \sin(kx)\right| \leq \frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}
\end{equation*}
and that the sequence $\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}} \to 0$ and is a decreasing sequence. So it should converge pointwise. But I am unsure how to proceed to show that the series cannot be the Fourier series of a RI-function. A hint that I was given was to use either Bessel's Inequality or Parseval's Identity. Some advice would be helpful.

Comment: Does RI stand for Riemann integrable?

Comment: The function is not Riemann integrable in $[-\pi,\pi]$ for example (or any interval of length $2\pi$ for that matter) because the series is unbounded around $x=0$. See @MatkViola's posting [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3784727/121671). The series does however converge to a Lebesgue integrable function (se for example theorem in this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4101128/121671)).

Comment: @OliverDíaz yes that’s what it means

Comment: That is what Thought.In any case, the first link  I sent to you will solve your problem.

Comment: a simpler way is just to note that RI functions are bounded so if $|f_{\alpha}| \le M$ then $\sum \frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}} \le M^2$ by Parseval and that can hold only for $\alpha>1/2$ (the link gives the asymptotic of the function which is harder)